# how can i get Elasticsearch Aggregations Terms total count?

Tags: elasticsearch

UCKeFu is a Spring Boot-based lightweight community system designed to provide a community platform for online communication.
Github URL([This is GitHub URL](https://github.com/uckefu/uckefu))

How can I use Top hits Aggregation to get the total count of terms?

Comment: Have you gone through the official documentation? It's pretty good -- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: can you add your settings/schema or show us the query you have been trying